# Error from "spring-test" and "spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

If we start from this  [Spring guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest) , and just add the following additional dependencies in the **build.gradle** (without modifying any Java code), there will be a lot of error messages coming out during project compilng.

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:1.1.5.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.1.RELEASE")
```

However, if we switch the version of spring-test from **4.1.1.RELEASE** to **3.2.11.RELEASE**, we can run this Spring project again.

Does anyone know the reason of this "conflict"?

Comment: Maybe a stack trace would help? Why do you need to specify the versions at all (the spring boot plugin should select the best match for you)?

Comment: Use `spring-boot-starter-test` instead, that will take care of using the version that belongs to the framework version you use. Scope of test should generally be `testCompile` instead of `compile`.

Comment: Thanks! By using spring-boot-starter-test, we can compile the project now!